# Woring with nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, undefined

I have the following code. I need to print only any `Nested Arrays`.

```
let newArray = ["Ameen", "John", ["Working", "Studying"], [10, 100, 30, 40]];

for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {

*// `Nested For Loop To Print The Nested Arrays`*

  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    if (Array.isArray(newArray[i])) {
      console.log(`Nested Array ${newArray[i][j]}`);
    }
  }
}
console.log(`Whole Array: ${newArray}`);
```

It's working fine, however, the problem here is that the `nested loop "j"` prints "undefined" after the last element of the first nested array `["Working", "Studying"]`.

I understand that because the index of `"i"` is increased to `"2"`, while the first nested array `["Working", "Studying"]` only has 2 elements which mean two `indexes (0,1)`. Thus, the "j" can't find the element with an `index of "2"` within the first nested array.

The question is, how to make the nested loop "j" to not print "undefined" elements caused by the parent for loop index "i"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the could be simplified by doing the following

```
const nestedArrayItems = newArray.filter(item => Array.isArray(item)).flat()
nestedArrayItems.forEach(nestedArrayItem => console.log(nestedArrayItem))
```

Comment: Amazing, I haven't studied filter and forEach yet. However, will take your solution as a reference in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that came to mind immediately that would prevent unnecessarily looping a second time would be:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; ++i) {
        if(Array.isArray(newArray[i])) {
            for (let j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; ++j) {
                if (newArray[i][j] != undefined) {
                    console.log(`Nested Array ${newArray[i][j]}`);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(`Whole Array: ${newArray}`);
```

Comment: I understand the pre and post increment. However, what difference does the "++i" make from the "i++" in for loops? I just want to know. Because I tried your code with the post increment "i++" and it works fine.  Is there a specific purpose? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After I squeezed my mind. I found the solution by adding another condition. Which is **If** the `newArray[i]` is an `Array` **and If** *(this is the added condition)* `newArray[i][j] !== undefined` as the following

```
for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    if (Array.isArray(newArray[i]) && newArray[i][j] !== undefined) {
      console.log(`Nested Array ${newArray[i][j]}`);
    }
  }
}
```

It's working as I wanted. However, I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve that.
I appreciate your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the nested sub arrays:

```js
const
    newArray = ["Ameen", "John", ["Working", "Studying"], [10, 100, 30, 40]];
    
    newArray   //PRINT only nested sub arrays
      .forEach(a => {
          if( Array.isArray(a) ) {
              console.log( a );
          }
      });
```

All the elements of the nested sub arrays:

```js
const
    newArray = ["Ameen", "John", ["Working", "Studying"], [10, 100, 30, 40]],
    
    nested = newArray   
      .reduce(
          (acc, curr) => [...acc, ...(Array.isArray(curr) ? curr : [])], []
      );
      
console.log( nested );
```